# Nginx configuration, huge amount of traffic or code issue?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

started using nginx as my back end server, so i have one proxy server where i put haproxy, 3 servers they are responsable to handle the traffic, 3 servers(2 gb, 2 core and 40 gb of SSD each one).
recently i started receiving this messages from nginx: "502 Bad Gateway", i have a traffic of 100k daily to my website. I don't know what to do anymore, i did everything and the servers are returning the same error and when i see the log is giving me this information:

"connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET ..."

I don't know if the amount of traffic is to high for this configuration or if the problem is with my nginx configuration, or with my php code. I don't know what to do anymore, i'd like to handle as many requests as possible.

I'm using PHP 7, ubuntu 16.04 and nginx 1.10.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a code issue, so off topic for SO.

Comment: Ok, do you  have sugestion how can i fix this error?

Comment: If you set your config file up by using online tutorials, and without first fully understanding what each configuration means, you may have effectively constrained your server to handle loads within specific constraints, and as a result your server is timing out or stalling when too many requests are being made. Go back to the basics, make sure you understand the meaning behind each line in your configuration file, and then carefully make adjustments, test, and keep an eye on your error logs.